# Formatting code snippets for blogging on Blogger

Tags: formatting, blogs, blogger

My blog is hosted on Blogger and I frequently post code snippets in `C` / `C#` / `Java` / `XML` etc. but I find the snippet gets "mangled".

Are there any web sites that I could use to parse the snippet beforehand and sort out the formatting, convert XML "`<`" to "`&lt;`" etc.

There are a numbers of questions around this area on SO but I couldn't find any that address this question directly.

`Edit:` For [@Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53501/rich) answer, site states *"To display the formatted code on your site, you need to get this CSS stylesheet, and add a reference to it in the `<head>` section of your page"*. That's the problem - you can't do this on Blogger AFAIK.

Comment: To display the formatted code: If you are using visual studio, then you can copy any type of code html/css/javascript/c# etc to blogger. You have to install visual studio productivity power tools: for more info read: http://coding-issues.blogspot.in/2013/10/copy-code-from-visual-studio-to-blogger.html

Comment: Try plug-in [Paste As Visual Studio Code](http://plugins.live.com/writer/detail/paste-as-visual-studio-code) for **Windows Live Writer** for Blogger offline editor. **WYSIWYG!**.

Comment: Are you missing **social content locker** like WordPress? now you can add this in blogger too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619171/social-content-locker-for-blogger-com-blogs-is-it-possible

Comment: You can use this web site for getting code spinet highlight code for various language. it gives you html you can post it in your blog http://hilite.me/

Comment: You can copy the code in intellij and paste in your blog. It works like a charm for me in my blog - https://codetails.blogspot.com/2017/11/design-pattern-in-java.html

Comment: Just add some simple CSS to your blog template like described here: https://www.diegodrivendesign.com/2018/09/add-code-snippets-in-your-blog-easily.html

Comment: different ways to add source code : https://www.sagapatra.in/2020/04/adding-code-snippet-in-blogger-post.html

Comment: if anyone comes across this topic in 2024, the short answer is https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js or deprecated https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify (both approaches require minimal modification of `<head>` in the template)

Answer (score 254, accepted):

I've created a blog post entry which explains how to add code syntax highlighting to blogger using the [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) 2.0

Here's my blog post:

http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/syntax-highlighting-with-blogger-engine.html

I'm quite impressed with what it can do.

Above Links stopped working.
Try using http://hilite.me/

Comment: @CraftyFella try publishing this: `static Dictionary<int, List<Delegate>>  _delegate = new Dictionary<int, List<Delegate>>();`

Comment: If you have < or > you'll have to html encode the text using something like http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/encode.aspx
I got the above working on my blog.

Comment: Should be 3 buttons at the top of the block for copying and pasting.

Comment: I found I needed to add the following CSS rule to prevent a vertical scrollbar appearing on all of my code snippets: .syntaxhighlighter{padding-bottom:1px;}

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this still works? I tried pasting the script tag just before the `</head>` section and added the pre tag around my code as well. No change though.

Comment: I spent a couple hours on it and I can't get this to work at all.

Comment: @Thepaulpage A lot of other people have been able to make it work.. what exactly is the problem.. Also you might want to consider yodaisgreen's answer as an alternative?

Comment: I find it has problems with generics... List<double> foo; would add an extra </double> tag to the end

Comment: Its not working fine for DYNAMIC view blogger, can you provide any alternative ? heres my blog with dynamic view http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/

Comment: Does not your website become slow while loading ?
Performance is effected. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm still can't get it to work

Comment: It looks like the code you are supposed to copy and paste is missing something at the top, specifically a <script> tag.

Comment: Though this service looks very promising, but while trying to make it work, I notice that it requires the inclusion of http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf. This is flash file, which I would not want to use in today's age. sad.

Comment: This doesn't work; Blogger removes all `http:` from the links, forcing them to use whatever protocol blogger uses (https) and alexgorbachev.com doesn't serve the files via HTTPS.

Comment: [Samuel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9009231/979772) is much better.

I don't like adding so many javascripts on my blog just for a mere syntax highlighting. Especially the pages which don't have any syntax to be high-lighted is an overkill.

Comment: The `syntaxhighlighter` seems to be gone or just not working now. As @divinedragon said, Samuel's answer of http://hilite.me/ is better

Answer (score 134):

Easiest way to share code is with a public gist.  Just write one up and paste in the embed code. Easy peasy.

http://gist.github.com

To address the search engine issue, one can use hidden `div` on the page as simple as:

```
<div style="display:none"> content </div>
```

Comment: dude, after using it for like 20 minutes, I can't thank you enough! The best formatting, no hussle, all the code is in one place, the posts look just beautiful, the editing of a post is incredibly easy as you don't mix up the code with the rest of the post and never worry that you do something stupid and lose/misformat any code. Thanx man!

Comment: The embed is javascript, there's a good chance it's invisible to search.  That pretty much kills it for blog posts.

Comment: I am currently using gists but I will probably use SyntaxHighlighter again. Not only gists use JavaScript (which makes them inaccessible in RSS readers as well) but also slow down page loading because every gist is downloaded sequentially blocking rendering. Not a good choice.

Comment: Thanks! You made my day. I'll just share this script for adding gist to blogger: https://github.com/moski/gist-Blogger

Comment: Very cool, but I've found that if I try and update my post, the editor has eaten the gist reference.

Comment: This idea really works fine! the result is just want I need; nicely formatted code...but I wont be going with it. I would rather have my post to be complete in and off itself. Having the code, which is part of the post, hosted elsewhere and included via js, just defeats that!

Comment: The gist is not necessary to be public. For secret gist, any one who has a link to it still can see it. But since you put the code to a public blog, public gist makes more sense.

Comment: It is said that a post by javascript such as gist is invisible to search. But I did find one of my posts which contains only gist of github.com appears on the first page of Google search result. So I guess the situation may be different now. But I am not 100% confirmed either.

Comment: you can always put your code in a div and give the style display:none

Comment: The only annoying thing with gists is that they are not visible in apps like pocket (readlater) and you have to load the webpage to see what's missing.

Comment: You can easily include the contents of gist in your blogger by copying the embedded script from gist and paste it in the html content of your blogspot blog. Cool

Comment: When posting a comment: "Your HTML cannot be accepted: Tag is not allowed: SCRIPT"

Answer (score 64):

For my blog I use http://hilite.me/ to format source code. It supports lots of formats and outputs rather clean html. But if you have lots of code snippets then you have to do a lot of copy paste. For formatting Python code I've also used [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) ([blog post](http://gissolved.blogspot.com/2009/05/python-toolbox-2-pygments.html)).

Comment: I used to use http://hilite.me/, but now I prefer http://dillinger.io/

Comment: I also prefer this to gist.github. No javascript and additional style / css required. Thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 47):

This css script might be useful to all - It is not for syntax highlighting but works well for presenting the source code in original format :

```
 <pre style="font-family: Andale Mono, Lucida Console, Monaco, fixed, monospace; 
                color: #000000; background-color: #eee;
                font-size: 12px; border: 1px dashed #999999;
                line-height: 14px; padding: 5px; 
                overflow: auto; width: 100%">
       <code style="color:#000000;word-wrap:normal;">

            <<<<<<<YOUR CODE HERE>>>>>>>

       </code>
 </pre>
```

**How to use :**

1. Paste this snippet in text editor,
2. paste your code in <<<<<<>>>>>> block.
3. Copy all and
4. paste to HTML view in blogger(or any other) post editor.

**BENEFITS :** Simple and easy to use, less configuration, easy to reconfigure, no extra software

Comment: The most simple and neat reply in my opinion. Just create an internal CSS and you're good to go.

Comment: working fine for me as well. simple solution

Answer (score 17):

**1.**  First, take backup of your blogger template
**2.**  After that open your blogger template (In Edit HTML mode) & copy the all css   [given in this link](http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Styles/SyntaxHighlighter.css) before `</b:skin>` tag
**3.**  Paste the followig code before `</head>` tag

```
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushDelphi.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

**4.**  Paste the following code before `</body>` tag.

```
<script language='javascript'>
dp.SyntaxHighlighter.BloggerMode();
dp.SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll('code');
</script>
```

**5.**  Save Blogger Template.
**6.**  Now syntax highlighting is ready to use you can use it with `<pre></pre>` tag.

```
<pre name="code">
...Your html-escaped code goes here...
</pre>

<pre name="code" class="php">
    echo "I like PHP";
</pre>
```

**7.**  You can Escape your code [here](http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/quick-escape/default.php).
**8.**  [Here](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Languages) is list of supported language for **`<class>`** attribute.

Comment: A nice link. Would be better if it color-formatted it! +1

Comment: @le_garry : thanks
I had face some problem while formatting code snippet so it is not in color.

Comment: See the answer by gissolved. The best highlighter I have seen so far, and it does color.

Comment: @le_garry Ohh you are taking about highlighting syntax in Blogger It work finely with color.
I misunderstand that you are taking about my answer So, I had sad that I had face some problm..

Comment: @MaheshMeniya i followed all the steps you wrote for syntax syntaxhighlighter but its not working, is there any extra think what I m missing?

Comment: @MaheshMeniya Thanks, It is formatting. But there is no nested indents. What could be the reason?

Comment: @MaheshMeniya Thank you so much for the answer. But when I click on http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Styles/SyntaxHighlighter.css
It gives error

Answer (score 16):

This can be done fairly easily with SyntaxHighlighter.  I have [step-by-step instructions for setting up SyntaxHighlighter in Blogger](http://blog.alainodea.com/tr/article/424/enabling-syntaxhighlighter-in-blogger-step-by-step) on my blog.  SyntaxHighlighter is very easy to use. It lets you post snippets in raw form and then wrap them in `pre` blocks like:

```
<pre name="code" class="brush: erlang"><![CDATA[
-module(trim).

-export([string_strip_right/1, reverse_tl_reverse/1, bench/0]).

bench() -> [nbench(N) || N <- [1,1000,1000000]].

nbench(N) -> {N, bench(["a" || _ <- lists:seq(1,N)])}.

bench(String) ->
    {{string_strip_right,
    lists:sum([
        element(1, timer:tc(trim, string_strip_right, [String]))
        || _ <- lists:seq(1,1000)])},
    {reverse_tl_reverse,
    lists:sum([
        element(1, timer:tc(trim, reverse_tl_reverse, [String]))
        || _ <- lists:seq(1,1000)])}}.

string_strip_right(String) -> string:strip(String, right, $\n).

reverse_tl_reverse(String) ->
    lists:reverse(tl(lists:reverse(String))).
]]></pre>
```

Just change the brush name to "python" or "java" or "javascript" and paste in the code of your choice.  The CDATA tagging let's you put pretty much any code in there without worrying about entity escaping or other typical annoyances of code blogging.

Comment: Your instructions worked better for me than the other leading answer. In case anyone finds themselves looking for them, [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/) is the list of bundled brushes and their aliases.

Answer (score 9):

http://formatmysourcecode.blogspot.co.uk/
works fine, you just copy , format, paste back.

Comment: I use this for my blog. For people who love colors, this does not color code though! I love it plain and simple.

Answer (score 6):

I have created a tool that gets the job done. You can find it on my blog:

[Free Online C# Syntax Highlighter](https://www.pvladov.com/p/syntax-highlighter.html)

Besides colorizing your C# code, the tool also takes care of all the '<' and '>' symbols converting them to '&lt;' and '&gt;'. Tabs are converted to spaces in order to look the same in different browsers. You can even make the syntax highlighter inline the CSS styles, in case you cannot or you do not want to insert a CSS style sheet in you blog or website.

Answer (score 5):

Here's [one site](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) that will format your code and spit out html, and it even includes inline styles for syntax coloring.  Might not work for *all* of your needs, but is a good start.  I believe he has made the source available if you want to extend it:

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I use a fairly low tech solution. I format the code using this [online syntax highlighting](http://tohtml.com/auto/) tool then just paste it into the blog

Comment: Yup - tohtml is the solution as recomended by the TechNet Wiki to paste code!

Comment: @Phil Hale  There is no indentation in that tool

Comment: This is the best solution I found till now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) with my Blogger powered blog. The actual site is hosted on my own server rather than Blogger's though (Blogger has an option of ftping posts to your own site), but having your own domain and web hosting only costs a couple of dollars a month.

Comment: Agreed - there are a number of options if I host my own blog but there doesn't seem to be much support when the blog is actually hosted by Blogger.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there have been some changes with [SyntaxHighlighter 2.0](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) that make it easier to use with Blogger.

There are [hosted versions](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Hosting) of the styles and Javascripts at: http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/

Answer (score 2):

Actually I had used (what else ;-) ) Vim for this: it has a 2html "plugin". See [the docs here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-file-remarks).

So as I edit my code, I just convert it to HTML and paste the results to Blogger's HTML editor.

Note: it's not so beautiful HTML (embeded css would be better), but it just works.

Oh: and it has syntax files for several languages which makes it pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Emacs specific answer :** As far as blogger is concerned, it allows inline css. The problem with javascript based highlighters is that you have to live with their color scheme or implement your own. But, like me, if you are a fan of your own emacs color scheme, you have a much better option available. I have hacked up the "htmlize.el" package for emacs to add the following four functions...

1. blog-htmlize-buffer
2. blog-htmlize-region
3. blog-htmlize-buffer-with-linum
4. blog-htmlize-region-with-linum

These functions will output copy-paste ready html (inline styled) in a new buffer in emacs, which you can directly use in your blog post. The output looks exactly same as you would see the code in emacs (including the color scheme).

Here is a [link to my blog](http://sujeet-gholap.blogspot.com/2011/05/code-snippets-for-blogging-made-easy.html), where you can find detailed information of how to use the "blog-htmlize.el" with emacs. This does away with html-encoding the "less than" and "greater than" signs also. And as emacs is doing all the highlighting and styling, you do not have to worry about whether the js library supports the language of your snippets, nor do you have to meddle with your template code in blogger.

You can find the [elisp file here](https://raw.github.com/gist/1047360/f58b73baf3fd045217f2da447ceba1a8d6b1bea6/blog-htmlize.el) (save the file as **blog-htmlize.el**)

Answer (score 0):

I rolled my own in F# (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228605/can-you-propose-a-more-elegant-way-to-tokenize-c-code-for-html-formatting) question), but it still isn't perfect (I just do regexps, so I don't recognise classes or method names etc.).

Basically, from what I can tell, the blogger editor will sometimes eat your angle brackets if you switch between Compose and HTML mode. So you have to paste into HTML mode then save directly. (I may be wrong on this, just tried now and it seems to work - browser dependent?)

It's horrible when you have generics!

Answer (score 0):

To post your html, javascript,c# and java you should convert special characters to HTML code. as `'<'` as `&lt;` and `'>'` to  `&gt;` and e.t.c..

Add this link [Code Converter](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?dpos=top&root=/ig&url=hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/102462998830435293579/post-Code.xml&safe=on) to iGoogle. This will help you to convert the special characters.

Then add [SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) new version to customize your code in blogger. But you should know How to configure the syntaxHighlighter in your blogger template.