# Posting source code in blogger- fails with C# containers

Tags: c#, html, containers, blogs, code-snippets

I tried the solutions that are posted in [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679189/formatting-code-snippets-for-blogging-on-blogger) and for the most part the code snippets are working, but there are some cases that are still getting garbled by Blogger when it publishes the blog.

In particular, declaring generic containers seems to be most troublesome. Please see the code examples on my blog: http://mlai-lirik.blogspot.com/, specifically the section where I declare the dictionary.

I want to display this:

```
static Dictionary<int, List<Delegate>> _delegate = new Dictionary<int,List<Delegate>>();
```

But blogger publishes this:

```
static Dictionary<int, list=""><delegate>> _delegate = new Dictionary<int, list=""><delegate>>();
```

And it caps the end of my code section with this:

```
</delegate></delegate></int,></delegate></int,>
```

Apparently blogger thinks that the `<int` and `<delegate>` portion of the dictionary are some sort of HTML tags and it automatically attempts to close them at the end of the code snippet. Does anybody know how to get around this problem?

**Update:**
I used [CraftyFella's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30317/craftyfella) solution http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/syntax-highlighting-with-blogger-engine.html and it causes the above-mentioned issues to occur (i.e. his solution does not work for the code snippets I posted).

I also tried wrapping my code snippets with the `<code></code>` tags, but that didn't work either.  The results were similarly disappointing: `Dictionary<int, List<string>> test = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();` turns into `Dictionary> test = new Dictionary>();`

Comment: Is there a question here? You said you used a solution. Doesn't that mean it's solved?

Comment: @Gabe, sorry... I forgot to mention: CraftyFella's results in the code snippets that I posted in my question. In other words, his solution does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced all of the `<` with `&lt;` and got [this](http://banzaimonkey.blogspot.com/2010/05/pie.html).  (Same trick I use on SO, actually.)

Comment: Yup, blogger kind of sucks...it's amazing they don't replace `<` and `>` automatically.  I always use the HTML editor because I got tired of their normal frontend screwing everything up.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is HTML encode your program. First replace all `&` with `&amp;`, then replace all `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Although the very last one isn't strictly required to get it to work, I think it's better for correctness.