# Code formatting SyntaxHighlighter for blogger throws error

Tags: syntax-highlighting, blogger

I'm using SyntaxHighlighter for blogger to format the code snippet I use in my blog. I followed steps given in a blog (http://concise-software.blogspot.com/2010/03/enabling-syntaxhighlighter-in-blogger.html) but then it throws error on page load of my blogger post saying "Can't find brush for : CSS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution from another thread on stackoverflow

> [Formatting code snippets for blogging on Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679189/formatting-code-snippets-for-blogging-on-blogger)

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a solution to this problem - Make sure you're referencing the shBrushCss.js library from within your <head></head> tag like so:

```
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Also, you can checkout this answer's source at http://oneqonea.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-do-i-add-syntax-highlighting-to-my.html

It's a really easy to follow blog that I wrote that covers adding syntax highlighting to your Blogger Blog from top to bottom in a few easy steps (with screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

If you run a blogger blog, you can follow the following steps explained bellow to integrate the SyntaxHighlighter.

I've nicely explained: [How to Add Syntax Highlighter to Blogger](http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/how-to-add-syntax-highlighter-to-blogger-or-blogspot-blog/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in the end of template head section this:

```
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current//styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPhp.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushBash.js'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPlain.js'/> 
<script> 
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = "http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf";
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

Next i wrote in my articles:

```
<pre class="brush:bash">
ls -al | grep .jpg
</pre>
```

You can example [here](http://dunmaksim.blogspot.ru/) see.