# How to add external script to blogger

Tags: blogger, syntaxhighlighter

My blog is hosted in blogger and i want to add code snippet to my blogs. I followed this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679189/formatting-code-snippets-for-blogging-on-blogger) on how to add [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) However i am not sure if that answer is still valid.

**Questions**
1>In html view, I don't see `<head>` element. Should i manually add `<head>` tag in html view? I thought html view is only for `body` element.

2>The SyntaxHighlighter scripts are hosted on [CDN here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/SyntaxHighlighter). Which scripts i need to add for C#, html and javascript?

3> What is shAutoloader.js? does it load all the scripts?

I have created a [sample blog here](http://lparab.blogspot.com/2017/03/my-first-blog.html) using Syntaxhighlighter but its not working

Comment: I checked the sample blog, the Syntax highlighter is not working because it has been loaded twice on the page (once via an HTML/JavaScript gadget named codehiglighter and another time via the post content.) Removing the repeat code from inside the post and then calling the Syntax highlighter (via `<script type='text/javascript'>SyntaxHighlighter.all()</script>` which should be placed near the `</body>` tag in the theme code (present in Theme > Edit HTML) would likely solve this issue)

Answer (score 0):

**Question no 1's Answer:**

If you don't see any  tag you need to add it in your template but normally every HTML as well as blogger template has a  tag closed by

**Second Question's Answer:**

You need to use following attribute to load external files, you can use multiple but keep them in  of template for better performance:

```
<script src="..../Link OF Code.js"></script>
```

You can use defer="defer" tag in case if you want to load a script after the whole page is loaded successfully, here is a sample:

```
<script defer="defer" src="..../Link OF Code.js"></script>
```

**Third Question's Answer:**

I don't know it.