# Blogger.com: How to embed formatted code snippet in a blog post?

Tags: javascript, css, html, blogs

I have a blog on blogger.com and would like to format my code example in my post.

What do I need to use to format the code snippet in my blog post?

Comment: Check the post out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679189/formatting-code-snippets-for-blogging-on-blogger/5615444#5615444). I used it create this [blogpost](http://codersspot.blogspot.com/2020/04/httpwebrequest-stringjoin-and.html)

Comment: https://www.sagapatra.in/2020/04/how-to-insert-code-snippet-in-blogger-articles.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Blogger.com blog with a tutorial post on how to do it [Syntax Highlighting with Blogger Engine](http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/syntax-highlighting-with-blogger-engine.html)
Either try using [Hilite](http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/syntax-highlighting-with-blogger-engine.html) for converting the code to embedable one or use [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) - this would be the easiest solution.

If by any chance it's outdated solution for your needs then read this: [Formatting code snippets for blogging on Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679189/formatting-code-snippets-for-blogging-on-blogger/9009231#9009231)

Add syntax highlighter in your template just above the  tag:

```
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPerl.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script language='javascript'> 
SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = 'http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf';
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

And then just add the code snippet.

Comment: This works fine, when our blog also uses `http` instead of `https` protocol. Chrome blocks all the calls from secure host (https) to http calls. Is there any other choice to use syntax highlighters for `https` blogs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @cdev is correct but outdated. June, 2021 the code that is working for me is:

```
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.0.1/styles/default.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.0.1/highlight.min.js'/>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.0.1/languages/dart.min.js'/>
<script>
    hljs.configure({cssSelector: &quot;code&quot;});
    hljs.highlightAll();
</script>
```

This previous code has to be added just before the `<head>` tag.

By the default the highlighted code has to be written under `<pre><code></code></pre>` if you also want to be able to hightlight code bettwen `<code></code>` you have to add this line `hljs.configure({cssSelector: &quot;code&quot;});`

This line `<script src='https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.0.1/languages/dart.min.js'/>` will make dart code to be highlighted. If the language you are using is not highlighted by default you may need to add a similar line. Check the [supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md)

You can see this article in [my blog](https://yayocode.com/post/p7lHc8OgQ4gU0vVn8Tqc)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting depends on what programming language code you are trying to highlight. Different languages will have to be highlighted differently.

It's best to use a third party library to take care of that for you.

Here's a tutorial on how to do that in Blogger: [How To Format Code Snippets In Blogger Posts](https://therealweblog.blogspot.com/2019/05/how-to-format-code-snippets-in-blogger.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highlight JS.

Go to themes and edit html, place below codes in .

```
<link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/styles/atom-one-dark-reasonable.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/highlight.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/languages/r.min.js'></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Write your code under `<pre><code></code></pre>`

Or you can use [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/) to create gists and copy embeded code to your blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: [Carbon](https://carbon.now.sh/)

I'm using it, and it's the best & fast & editable tool that I used for this purpose.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31835828)

Answer (score -1):

Syntax highlighting works perfectly at blogger

But I suggest you to NOT use Blogger, there are better alternatives available now a days (all free like blogger).
proof: Search on google "Top Blogging sites", blogger will be seen NO Where.